# filter data with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    diets: ['vegan', 'diary free', 'gluten free']
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    diets: ['vegan', 'gluten free']
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    diets: ['vegan', 'diary free']
  }
];

const filters = ['gluten free', 'diary free'];
```

I have array of objects and want to filter out ones that satisfies all the filter values.
Filtered data's `diets` should have all of `filters`.

Comment: `data.filter((o) => filters.every(Array.prototype.includes, o.diets))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    diets: ['vegan', 'diary free', 'gluten free'],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    diets: ['vegan', 'gluten free'],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    diets: ['vegan', 'diary free'],
  },
];

const filters = ['gluten free', 'diary free'];

const filteredData = data.filter((item) =>
  filters.every((filter) => item.diets.includes(filter))
);

console.log(filteredData);
```

*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter*

Comment: Thank you! Now I finally know the existence of every method.